# How to add a phrase when other column is populated?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Example: When column A is populated, a phrase, a word or anything of my choosing is added to Column B.

I would like this to be added using a script.
Here is a link to my sheet, permission must be granted as this is under a work account.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFlBlVuGgHRD96fqIAGdlQLohCmwjmxILt95KZNJ_2A/edit#gid=0

I can script a timestamp, so my guess is the setup has to be similar, just without the time format. So this is what I have so far. Not exactly sure where to go from here.

```
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Name of sheet here")
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var header = headers[0].indexOf("Name of column") + 1; // Name of Colum I want to add phrase
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Name of column") + 1; // Name of Column that will be populated with data

}
```

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of missing pieces of information here. I assume, since you're using `e.source`, that you're using this in a `onEdit()` function. But the actual use case isn't so clear. You're not using most variables you're declaring, nor indicating how you would need to use them. Some are duplicates (`header` is identical to `orderCol`, e.g.). So, can you please elaborate a bit, and share your spreadsheet with a description of your starting point and desired outcome?

Comment: Hello @BenoîtWéry, I have provided an example image as well as a link to my spreadsheet. Please note, this is under a work account and permission must be granted. As soon as you need edit access, I can provide this right away as I'm actively working so getting to my email is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry the English

You can easily get around your need by writing in D1 the following formula

= {"Populate with phrase"; ARRAYFORMULA (IF (C2: C <> ""; "email@phrase.com"; ""))}

After that erase everything from D2, enter values in from C2 and check the result!

Sidney

Comment: Thank you Sidney, this will be very useful as well. If I wanted to add a secondary column with another phrase when say Column A is populated with data, how would you achieve that with this method?

**EXAMPLE**

When Column A is populated, fill _**Column C**_ with "_phrase@email.com_", and fill _**Column D**_ with "Random Phrase".

Comment: @Sidney that's indeed cleaner and better, if the original requirement "I would like this to be added using a script" can be left out. @FeatherDuster just adjust the formula provided by Sidney, and put it in C1 instead of D1: `= {"Header Col C","Header Col D"; ARRAYFORMULA (IF (A2:A <> "", {"email@phrase.com","Random Phrase"}, {"",""}))}`; then delete C2:D and start putting content in A2:A.

Comment: @Benoît Wéry As I'm learning to write competent scripts, as that is what I primarily use, I think it would be beneficial to those who might want to learn both ways for the same scenario. Would you agree? Thank you to the both of you!

Comment: I didn't mean to start a debate :-) but if you ask: my personal approach is that it's always better to use functions when possible, scripts should be reserved for cases where formulas can't address the need. Just a personal opinion though. Anyway, glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value to add is identical and static as in your example, this should work. I've put a few comments in there to explain my assumptions / hypotheses.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 3.0 && e.range.getRow() > 1.0){ // You may need to add a condition on the sheet too if it should only apply to as pecific sheet and not all of them
    var valueToAdd = "email@phrase.com"; // Whatever you want to add to column D, assuming it's static, else I'll need to know more about the value to add (how to generate / where to fetch)
    if (typeof e.value != "object") e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1).setValue(valueToAdd);  
    // Use commented line below if you also want to remove the content of column D when column C is set back to blank. 
    // else e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1).setValue("");  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you set this up to be only applied to a specific sheet? Thank you

Comment: Just add to the conditions in the first `if` the following clause: `&& e.range.getSheet().getName() == "your_sheet_name"` (before the closing parenthesis).

Comment: I do have one more question, and it's regarding flexibility of this script. Say, I want to make a change where I need this to look at a different column and parse the desired phrase in a different column. How would I go about doing that?

**Example:**
If Column D gets populates with data, 
Then Column G populates the desired phrase

Comment: the column where changes are detected is the one in the first `if`, so in the current case, change the value `3.0` with whatever column index (starting at 1 for A, 2 for B, ...) you need to consider. The column in which you're writing is defined in the 4th line: `getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1)`. In there, change the part `e.range.getColumn() + 1` into a number that corresponds to the column index too (I could have just written `4` in the current case, but I just assumed it would always be the next column anyway).

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for this, much is appreciated, sorry you had to look at my chicken scratch script! Have a great day and thank you for the lesson!